# Linq where doesnt seem to work .Where

Tags: c#, linq

here is my linq code i want to filter a list with linq where however it doesnt seem to work in this case and doesnt return a list with the matches for ItemName==stringItemName,

```
JsonResult jso = Json(ItemList
                .Where(x => x.ItemName==stringItemName)
                .Select(x => new { x.Year }).Distinct()
                .Select(x => new { Text = x.Year.ToShortDateString(), Value = x.ToShortDateString() }));
```

nor does

```
JsonResult jso = Json(ItemList
                .Where(x => x.ItemName.Equals(stringItemName))
                .Select(x => new { x.Year }).Distinct()
                .Select(x => new { Text = x.Year.ToShortDateString(), Value = x.ToShortDateString() }));
```

I wonder why its worked in the past in a different scenario but wouldnt work now. What am i doing wrong..

Comment: is it string property you are comparing?

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work? do you get an error message, or doesn't it compile or does it and just doesn't give the expected result?

Comment: how do you know the problem is in `Where` and its not in `Select` maybe? try to split them and check this with debugger.

Comment: also you might want to fix this `Value = x..ToShortDateString()`, might cause whatever the problem is what you have

Comment: yes i am comparing strings.

Comment: What does it doesn't work mean? You could instead select your Boolean and see whether the result set looks as you expect.

Comment: Apologies when I said it doesnt work, i dont get the expected resultset when the filter criteria matches i.e. ItemName == stringItemName matches

Comment: @Gunther34567 it is not a problem with the x.ToShortDateString() i have fixed it here.

Comment: `Select(x => new {x.Year})` returns an `IEnumerable<int>`. You can't get the `Year` property of an int.

Comment: @FernandoMatsumoto - No, it returns an anonymous type with a single property called `Year`.

Comment: @Enigmativity My bad. Didn't realize that, though the code still won't compile since you can't call methods on anonymous types.

Comment: @FernandoMatsumoto - Yes, you can call methods on anonymous types. What do you mean?

Comment: @Enigmativity I mean you can't call methods that are not defined in `object`. For instance, you can't call `ToShortDateString` on an anonymous type.

Comment: @FernandoMatsumoto - Sure, but you can call method on the properties of anonymous variables - like `x.Year.ToShortDateString()`.

Comment: @Enigmativity I never said you couldn't. And the OP is trying to call `ToShortDateString` directly on `x`.

Comment: Why are you creating anonymous type with a single property Year in the first select, instead of just returning the Year value?

Comment: @FernandoMatsumoto - Oh, yes. Sorry. I thought I was missing something.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was error with the underlying data. I have added .Trim() and now the same code block works as intended.

```
JsonResult jso = Json(ItemList
            .Where(x => x.ItemName.Trim().Equals(stringItemName))
            .Select(x => new { x.Year }).Distinct()
            .Select(x => new { Text = x.Year.ToShortDateString(), Value = x.ToShortDateString() }));
```